# VS2013 new Language Implementation Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, mef, vsix

I want to implement a custom scripting language in Visual Studio 2013. After vicious Googling I found [the Ook Language](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Ook-Language-sample-VS-2013-92660d3d) but I'm looking for something that is a bit more complicated and starts from the beginning *(like a `IVsLanguageInfo`)*. Other examples seem rather dated...

The end goal is to claim a file *.extension* and handle Syntax Highlighting, Intellisense and the likes for it in the Visual Studio editor.

*Can anyone point me in the right direction? Considering the fact that extending Visual Studio is absolutely new territory to me. I'm cool with either C# or C++ sample code.*

Comment: The PTVS-project might be of your interest: http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Matze Thanks, will look into it. Seems to be what I need...